# bash if statement checking path matches list of paths

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a script that I need to check for the existence of directories on an external storage, and it should exit if any do not match - except for those listed in the file `list`

they are listed with their full paths and sometimes contain special characters, spaces, `[]`,`{}` and not utf characters. there is one path per line.

`$ cat /data/list`

```
/data/test [test] {test}
/data/test directory
/data/test name
```

i have the script working without the exclusion list. the checking against an exclusion list does not work. i.e. it does not break when `/data/test [test] {test}` is found on the list, and instead, exits because it doesn't exist at `/external/data/`.

i think the problem is matching due to the formatting of $(< /data/list) without line breaks, but in my experiments with and without `""` and `=~` etc. have been fruitless.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /data/storage/*; do
        if [[ ! -h "$i" ]]; then
                if [[ "$i" == "$(< /data/list)" ]]; then 
                break; else
                        if [ -e "/external//data/${i##*/}" ]; then
                        echo "/external/data/${i##*/} exists!"; else
                        echo "$i doesn't exist at /external/data/${i##*/}";
                        exit 1
                        fi
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: You're comparing each filename to the *entire* contents of `/data/list`, which doesn't seem like what you want. You need either an explicit loop over the lines of `/data/list`, or an implicit loop by calling something like `grep` to do the loop for you.

Comment: exactly, what i really want is to combine `for i in /data/storage*` and `while read` but i can't figure it out

Comment: maybe change `if [[ "$i" == "$(< /data/list)" ]]; then ` to `if grep -q "$i" /data/list ; then` ... . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to shellter, i got this working using `grep -F` to match literal strings

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /data/storage/*; do
        if [[ ! -h "$i" ]]; then
                if grep -Fqx "$i" /data/list ; then
                echo "found ${i##*/} in list" || break; else
                        if [[ -e "/external/storage${i##*/}" ]]; then
                        echo "/external/storage/${i##*/} exists!"; else
                        echo "${i##*/} doesn't exist at /external/storage/${i##*/}";
                        exit 1
                        fi
                fi
        fi
done
```